# $X_n$ ($n\ge1)$ is sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}}=0.001$ then

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $X_n$ ($n\ge1)$ is sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}}=0.001$ then,

$(A)\ \ X_n$ is a bounded sequence

$(B)\ \ X_n$ is a unbounded sequence

$(C)\ \ X_n$ is a Convvergent sequence

$(D)\ \ X_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence

I can only think of this particular case.

$\text{convergent sequence}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\text{convergent sequence}\cdot \text{convergent sequence} =$finite limit

Therefore it is convergent but I think its not a correct way to solve this problem.

How do I figure out what is our sequence behavior just on the basis of limits provided?

Comment: Think of some very simple examples of sequences that satisfy $x_n/n\rightarrow 0.001$. This is an easy way to get intuition and to cross several of the options off your list.

Comment: $0.001\cdot n$ makes it unbounded is true for all?

Comment: I agree $x_n=0.001 n$ works.  So, with this example, which of the options can you cross off the list?

Comment: $A$ and $C$ for sure.D too

Comment: So with this method you have eliminated all but one choice (which is useful).  To solidify the answer, it remains to understand why **all**  sequences that satisfy $x_n/n\rightarrow 0.001$ are unbounded.

Comment: @Michael I feel so dumb this problem was not hard at all and doesn't deserve to be put here. Should I delete it ?

Comment: No, I would not delete it.  This method of exploring examples is useful for intuition and narrows down the choices here.  But it still is useful to understand why B is a correct choice.  For example, what would happen if you assumed $-M \leq x_n \leq M$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you considered the example $x_n = 0.001 n$ and that correctly eliminated choices A, C, D.  So B is the only remaining choice.

It is useful to know why B holds true, that is, why **any** sequence $\{x_n\}$ that satisfies $x_n/n\rightarrow 0.001$ must be unbounded. Knowing that it is true for a particular example is not good enough.  One way to explore this is through "proof by contradiction": Assume $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, so that there is a finite number $M$ such that
$$ -M \leq x_n \leq M \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Now reach a contradiction with the assumption $x_n/n\rightarrow 0.001$.

Comment: I can't think of a bounded sequence $x_n$ that satisfies this $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}}=0.001$.Can we?

Answer (score 1):

$(A)$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{M}{n}} = 0 < 0.001$

$(C)$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}}=0.001 \implies 0=\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{L}{n}}=0.001$.

$(D)$ If $(x_{n})$ is eventually constant, we have the same case as $(C)$.

Otherwise, $(x_{n})$ is strictly decreasing and $(x_{n})$ is eventually always negative which implies that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_{n}}{n}$ exists, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_n}{n}} < 0 < 0.001 $.

Then the answer must be $(B)$.

Finding an example (that satisfies the hypothesis but just so happens to not satisfy any of the other properties...) may also work as you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

A direct proof.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n/n = c > 0$
then, for all large enough $n$,
$x_n/n > c/2$
so $x_n > cn/2$
and this is unbounded.